# Convert crontab commands to systemd?

Tags: conversion, cron, systemd, crontab

I am using crontab in centos and I am having many problems such as some commands are not executed or simply not running any and simply deleting the crontab file and putting the same lines back is solved, which is not a problem with the commands that Im using

I have seen systemd as an alternative, but I am going a little crazy to understand how it works and how to convert my commands to systemd.

I am going to put some commands that I use since I do not know if it is possible to add them to systemd by not seeing any example of anyone on the internet similar:

```
*/10 * * * * cd /usr/share/nginx/html/example.com; php wp-cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1
0 0 */3 * * date=date -I; /usr/bin/mysqldump -uadminbla -p blablabla example_admin >/root/copias/example$date.sql
0 0 */3 * * date=date -I; zip -r > /root/copias/copia-archivos-html-webs$date.zip /usr/share/nginx/html
0 0 */2 * * find /root/copias/* -mtime +10 -type f -delete
15 15 * * * wget -q -O /dev/null https://example.com/?run_blabla=blabla
```

Comment: Before doing so, have you actually investigated _why_ some of the commands are not being run? Missing jobs are very unusual given cron's overall track record, and systemd is not a magic wand that'll fix everything.

Comment: a bad format error appeared, but nevertheless the format is correct, eliminating crontab and copying the same lines again works, other commands are the same only changes the web and through the console they work but in cronjob no, so I desist for full of cronjob

Comment: You might want to give https://github.com/systemd-cron/systemd-cron-next a try. "It works by parsing crontab and anacrontab files from usual places like /etc/crontab and /var/spool/cron and generating systemd timers and services."